# Printing Files in Reverse Order Linux

Tags: linux

What is the command to print a file in reverse order in linux ?

## Example

```
Input File
1
2
3

Output File
3
2
1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate on Superuser: http://superuser.com/questions/481423/reverse-order-using-command

Answer (score 2):

Use [`tac`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tac_%28Unix%29):

```
tac filename
```

to reverse the order of lines in the input.

Alternatively, you could use `sed`:

```
sed '1!G;h;$!d' filename
```

Comment: +1 for tac (backwards cat). Totally forgot about that guy! :)